# define connection in odbc package for shiny app

Tags: r, sql-server, shiny, odbc

I am fetching the data from MS SQL database via `odbc` backage in `Shiny`.
I would like to avoid repeating this `con` function in every reactive function and just run it once and use it. Therefore, I have put it on the server function like :

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                   Driver = "MSODBC",
                   Server = "myserver",
                   Database = "mydatabase",
                   UID = "User",
                   PWD = "Pass",
                   encoding = "windows-1252",
                   Port = 1433) 
on.exit(odbc::dbDisconnect(con))


  main <- reactive({

    squery = dbSendQuery(con,"myQuery",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    parameterNmaes = dbFetch(squery )

    result= list(parameterNmaes = parameterNmaes)
    return(result)
  })
 }
```

But this does not work and I'm getting the following error :

```
Warning: Error in new_result: external pointer is not valid
  82: <Anonymous>
```

By Putting the `con` function inside the reactive function `main`, everything is fine :

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

  main <- reactive({
  con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                       Driver = "MSODBC",
                       Server = "myserver",
                       Database = "mydatabase",
                       UID = "User",
                       PWD = "Pass",
                       encoding = "windows-1252",
                       Port = 1433) 
    on.exit(odbc::dbDisconnect(con))


    squery = dbSendQuery(con,"myQuery",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    parameterNmaes = dbFetch(squery )

    result= list(parameterNmaes = parameterNmaes)
    return(result)
  })
 }
```

Even I tried to export the `con` function as result to use it in another reactive function like :

```
result= list(parameterNmaes = parameterNmaes, con = con)
sub1 <- reactive({
con <- main()$con
})
```

but I am getting the same error !
So far the only solution was repeating the `con` function over and over again in all reactive functions !
Any smart idea to prevent this pointless repeating database connection will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try doing ```con <<- dbConnect(...)```.  If that doesn't work, have you tried placing it in a global.R file?

Comment: @TTS I have tried both, does not work !

Comment: What if you used a reactive value such as `init <- shiny::reactiveValues(con = con())` ? Then sub1 <- reactive({
con <- init$con
})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run this small app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage()

server <- function(input, output, session){
  on.exit(cat("hello"))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

then you will see "hello" printed in the R console whenever the app starts. That's because Shiny has finished to execute the `server` function. So `dbDisconnect` is executed in your app whenever the app starts.

I would try

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                   Driver = "MSODBC",
                   Server = "myserver",
                   Database = "mydatabase",
                   UID = "User",
                   PWD = "Pass",
                   encoding = "windows-1252",
                   Port = 1433) 
  onStop(function() odbc::dbDisconnect(con))

  main <- reactive({
    squery = dbSendQuery(con,"myQuery",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    parameterNmaes = dbFetch(squery )
    result= list(parameterNmaes = parameterNmaes)
    return(result)
  })
 }
```